# Calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+z)^{2+\gamma}} \ _2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

On page $46$ of [this paper](https://arxiv-export1.library.cornell.edu/abs/2207.12363v1), the authors say that

> By writing the Gauss Hypergeometric function in series, integrating and summing again we find the following expression
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+z)^{2+\gamma}} \ _2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)\,dz=\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac\gamma2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\gamma-1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\gamma}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac\gamma2\right)}.$$

I can do the first two steps: writing the Gauss Hypergeometric function in series and integrating, but I don't know how to "sum again" to get the neat result. Let me first explain the notations. Here $\gamma\in(0,1)$ is a given parameter and $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The [Gauss Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series) is defined for $|z|<1$ by the series
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!},$$
where the (rising) [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $(x)_n$ is defined by
$$(x)_n=\begin{cases} 1, & n=0,\\ x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1), & n\geq1.\end{cases}$$
It follows from definition that $(x)_n=\Gamma(x+n)/\Gamma(x)$ for $x>0$.

**My calculation.** By definition,
\begin{align*}
_2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(1+\frac\gamma2\right)_n\left(\frac32\right)_n}{(3)_n}\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac\gamma2+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac\gamma2\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac32+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(3\right)}{\Gamma\left(3+n\right)}\frac{4^n}{n!}\frac{z^n}{(1+z)^{2n}}.
\end{align*}
Now, we do the integration. Change the variable $z=\tan^2\theta$ gives that $\frac{dz}{d\theta}=2\tan\theta\frac1{\cos^2\theta}$ and thus
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1+z)^{2+\gamma+2n}}\,dz&=2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\tan^{2n}\theta}{(1+\tan^2\theta)^{2+\gamma+2n}}\tan\theta\frac1{\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos^{2n+2\gamma+1}\theta\sin^{2n+1}\theta\,d\theta\\
&=B(n+\gamma+1,n+1)=\frac{n!\Gamma(n+\gamma+1)}{\Gamma(2n+\gamma+2)}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+z)^{2+\gamma}} \ _2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)\,dz=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac\gamma2+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac\gamma2\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac32+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}\frac{2\cdot 4^n}{(n+2)!}\frac{\Gamma(n+\gamma+1)}{\Gamma(2n+\gamma+2)}.$$
I can do a little more cancellation between the the numerator and the denominator. But I still don't know how to calculate the sum even after the simplication.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E20) help?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for your comment! That is a informative page! But I'm not sure about whether we can write the last sum in the post to a form $F(a,b;c;1)$. At least I can't see how to do it.

Comment: Yes, it is not immediate. One possible step you could make is using $$
\frac{{\Gamma \left( {1 + \frac{\gamma }{2} + n} \right)}}{{\Gamma (2n + \gamma  + 2)}} = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{3}{2}} \right)}}{{2^{2n + \gamma } \Gamma \left( {\frac{3}{2} + \frac{\gamma }{2} + n} \right)}}.
$$

Comment: @Gary Why this formula holds?

Comment: @Gary Oh. Never mind. I've figured it out. It is a direct consequence of the Legendre duplication formula!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

If the series manipulations are giving you trouble or if you just would rather avoid them for whatever reason, it is in fact possible to do the calculation entirely with integrals.

---

Given $(a,b,c,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that $0<b<c\land z\le1$, Euler's integration formula for the Gauss hypergeometric function states

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{b-1}\left(1-t\right)^{c-b-1}}{\left(1-zt\right)^{a}}=\operatorname{B}{\left(b,c-b\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)};~~~\small{a+b-c<0\lor z<1}.$$

---

Suppose $0<\gamma<1$. We find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\gamma\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2+\gamma}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{2},\frac32;3;\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2+\gamma}}\cdot\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}{\left[1-\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}t\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2+\gamma}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}{\left[1-\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}t\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left[\left(1+x\right)^{2}\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}{\left[1-\frac{4x}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}t\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}{\left[\left(1+x\right)^{2}-4xt\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}{\left[x^{2}-2(2t-1)x+1\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}-2ux+1\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{u+1}{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}-2ux+1\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}-2ux+1\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-\infty}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}-2ux+1\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}};~~~\small{\left[(x,u)\mapsto(-x,-u)\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}-2ux+1\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{\left(y^{2}+1-u^{2}\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}};~~~\small{\left[x=y+u\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1-u^{2}\right)}{\left[\left(1-u^{2}\right)z^{2}+1-u^{2}\right]^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}};~~~\small{\left[y=z\sqrt{1-u^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{\left(1-u^{2}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\left(1+z^{2}\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{\left(1-u^{2}\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\left(1+z^{2}\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{v}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-v\right)^{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\left(1+w\right)^{1+\frac{\gamma}{2}}};~~~\small{\left[u=\sqrt{v}\land z=\sqrt{w}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{-1/2}\left(1-v\right)^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+w}\right)^{\frac32+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{\left(\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^{1/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{-1/2}\left(1-v\right)^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t\right)^{-\frac12+\frac{\gamma}{2}}}{t^{1/2}};~~~\small{\left[w=\frac{t}{1-t}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,v^{1/2-1}\left(1-v\right)^{1-\frac{\gamma}{2}-1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{1/2-1}\left(1-t\right)^{\frac12+\frac{\gamma}{2}-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,1-\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)}\,\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac12,\frac12+\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Cheers. =)

---

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! It is impressive! For those who (including myself) are intersted in Euler's integration formula, [this web-page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6) is useful.

Comment: @Feng dead link :(

Comment: @clathratus It should link to Chapter 15 of the book "NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions" by Frank W. J. Olver, Daniel W. Lozier, Ronald F. Boisvert and Charles W. Clark. They have a web-page version of the book. But I don't know why the link is broken now. Maybe it will be fixed several days later.

Comment: @Feng: Yes that page's link seems to be working again.

Answer (score 7):

*It works*

Using
$$\ _2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;t\right)=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{\gamma }{2};3;t\right)$$ then
$$\, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{2},1+\frac{\gamma }{2};3;t\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi }}\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)! \left(n+\frac{\gamma }{2}\right)!}{\frac{\gamma}{2}!\, n!\, (n+2)!}\,t^n$$
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+z)^{2+\gamma}} \ _2F_1\left(1+\frac\gamma2,\frac32;3;\frac{4z}{(1+z)^2}\right)\,dz$$ $$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n+1} \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)! \left(\frac{\gamma
   }{2}+n\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\frac{\gamma }{2}!\, n! \,(n+2)!}\int_0^\infty z^n (z+1)^{-\gamma -2 n-2}\,dz$$
$$\int_0^\infty z^n (z+1)^{-\gamma -2 n-2}\,dz=\frac{\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (n+\gamma +1)}{\Gamma (2 n+\gamma +2)}$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{1-\gamma }\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \,\Gamma (n+\gamma +1)}{\Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{\gamma }{2}\right)\, \Gamma (n+3)\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\gamma
   +3}{2}\right)}=-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2-\gamma }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\gamma
   -1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1-\gamma }{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{\gamma +2}{2}\right)}$$ which is the same as the rhs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not very familiar with these special functions. I have two questions. Why $$\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac\gamma2+n\right)}{\Gamma(2n+\gamma+2)}=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{2^{2n+\gamma}\Gamma\left(\frac{\gamma+3}2+n\right)},$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{1-\gamma }\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma (n+\gamma +1)}{\Gamma (n+3)\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\gamma
   +3}{2}\right)}=-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2-\gamma }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{\gamma
   -1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1-\gamma }{2}\right)}$$

Comment: @Feng. If you look at the first line *"Using ..."*, the coefficients express in a different manner.

Comment: I can understand all the formulas expect the last line. I also get them in my post. I don't understand why you need your first line "Using..." Changing the order of $3/2$ and $1+\gamma/2$ doesn't change all things I've written in my post. Am I missing anything important? I still can't see how the term $\Gamma\left(\frac{\gamma+3}2+n\right)$ comes...

Comment: I've figured out the first question of mine in my first comment. It is a direct consequence of the Legendre duplication formula! What about the second question?

Comment: Now I also have figured out the second question of mine, using https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4#E20 and then Legendre duplication formula several times. It is not trivial, IMO. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @Feng. Sorry to be late. I had to go and rest. Glad to know your progress. Cheers :-)

Comment: No need to be soory. It's OK. If you have a rather simple way to prove the final identity I mentioned, you can add it to your answer. I like your answer more, which is mainly along the same way as I thought. If you're willing to add more details, I will accept yours. If you're tired and don't want spend time, it is OK, too. I have proved the result with your help. As for other people who may run into this question, if they have the same question as I, I'm sure that they can solve it under the help of my earily comments.